# DB Error: no such field Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: When Creating Reports

Tags: wordpress, civireport, error

I get the following error when trying to create new reports or edit existing ones.

> DB Error: no such field

> Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in ***/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107

I have double checked that we DID run the upgrade script.

"Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM 4.7.1"
I have run SELECT version FROM civicrm_domain on the database to verify this is the case.

We are the most up to date Wordpress 4.4.2

I had this error previously and realized it was an extension causing the problem. Disabled the extension and all was right again. Now ALL extensions have been disabled and we are getting the error again.

ETA - Debugging Log

```
# 0 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
# 1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
# 2 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
# 3 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_report_instance (domain_id , title , report_id , descript...")
# 4 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-19, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_report_instance (domain_id , title , report_id , descript...")
# 5 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -19, NULL, NULL, "INSERT INTO civicrm_report_instance (domain_id , title , report_id , descript...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
# 6 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(895): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1054 ** Unknown column 'created_id' in 'field list'")
# 7 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
# 8 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("INSERT INTO civicrm_report_instance (domain_id , title , report_id , descript...")
# 9 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2435): DB_common->query("INSERT INTO civicrm_report_instance (domain_id , title , report_id , descript...")
# 10 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1060): DB_DataObject->_query("INSERT INTO civicrm_report_instance (domain_id , title , report_id , descript...")
# 11 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(467): DB_DataObject->insert()
# 12 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/BAO/ReportInstance.php(109): CRM_Core_DAO->save()
# 13 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/BAO/ReportInstance.php(184): CRM_Report_BAO_ReportInstance::add((Array:93))
# 14 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Instance.php(361): CRM_Report_BAO_ReportInstance::create((Array:93))
# 15 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php(2608): CRM_Report_Form_Instance::postProcess(Object(CRM_Report_Form_Member_Detail))
# 16 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Member/Detail.php(339): CRM_Report_Form->beginPostProcess()
# 17 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(423): CRM_Report_Form_Member_Detail->postProcess()
# 18 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Submit.php(74): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
# 19 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Submit->perform(Object(CRM_Report_Form_Member_Detail), "submit")
# 20 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Report_Form_Member_Detail), "submit")
# 21 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("submit")
# 22 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
# 23 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Page/Report.php(72): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Report_Form_Member_Detail", NULL, NULL)
# 24 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Report_Page_Report->run((Array:4), NULL)
# 25 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
# 26 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
# 27 /***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1214): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
# 28 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
# 29 /***/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(525): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
# 30 /***/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(236): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
```

Comment: To solve your problem, we'll need to see the expanded debugging information.  In CiviCRM, please go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save".  Repeat the problem that caused your error, and you'll see much a much more detailed error.  Please update this question with the expanded error and backtrace - and don't forget to disable debugging/backtrace when you're done!

Comment: I don't know what happened to my last comment, but I did update with the error log.

Comment: So it appears that civicrm_report_instance is not a table in my database. JOY. Anybody have the SQL to create that table?

Answer (score 1):

That's odd that your `civicrm_report_instance` table is missing, and it suggests that maybe the upgrade got interrupted?  I'd personally rollback and re-upgrade to be safe.  If that's not an option, go into your `civicrm` directory, then into the `sql` directory.  The `civicrm.mysql` file contains all the SQL needed to generate a blank Civi database - you can find the `civicrm_report_instance` SQL specific to your version of Civi.